# Can't figure out how to get specific array item in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is probably really easy but i've been working on this for a while and i can't seem to figure it out.

I have a class where i can do print_r($return->stream) in php and I get this array

```
[array] => stdClass Object
    (
        [_id] => 12299116736
        [game] => League of Legends
        [viewers] => 8520
        [created_at] => 2014-12-23T00:38:18Z
        [_links] => stdClass Object
            (
                [self] => https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/trick2g
            )

        [preview] => stdClass Object
            (
                [small] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_trick2g-80x45.jpg
                [medium] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_trick2g-320x180.jpg
                [large] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_trick2g-640x360.jpg
                [template] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_trick2g-{width}x{height}.jpg
            )

        [channel] => stdClass Object
            (
                [_links] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [self] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g
                        [follows] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/follows
                        [commercial] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/commercial
                        [stream_key] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/stream_key
                        [chat] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/trick2g
                        [features] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/features
                        [subscriptions] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/subscriptions
                        [editors] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/editors
                        [videos] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/videos
                        [teams] => http://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/trick2g/teams
                    )

                [background] => 
                [banner] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/trick2g-channel_header_image-a712bd1af57ae2ee-640x125.jpeg
                [broadcaster_language] => en
                [display_name] => Trick2g
                [game] => League of Legends
                [logo] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/trick2g-profile_image-49f3cee5732742ee-300x300.jpeg
                [mature] => 1
                [status] => Godyr Gates > Godyr Devourer | Learn what not to do | 600,000 Soon | Xmas 24hour Kappa Lets go!
                [partner] => 1
                [url] => http://www.twitch.tv/trick2g
                [video_banner] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/trick2g-channel_offline_image-14cb5e9c1e344836-640x360.png
                [_id] => 28036688
                [name] => trick2g
                [created_at] => 2012-02-06T21:16:52Z
                [updated_at] => 2014-12-23T09:42:35Z
                [delay] => 0
                [followers] => 598315
                [profile_banner] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/trick2g-profile_banner-d326186fdd09f433-480.jpeg
                [profile_banner_background_color] => #030303
                [views] => 76721348
                [language] => en
            )

    )
```

I am trying to get "preview->small" into a variable but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: try this `$array->preview->small`

Comment: $return->stream->preview->small doesn't help?

Comment: It was that simple, wow. I always try to overdo things when it's really this simple. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
echo $array->preview->small;
```

Where `$array` is the main array.

`preview` is object.

and

in that object, there is a property `small`

Comment: array contains stdclass object so it should be $array->preview->small

Comment: Check what OP asked, and check the structure of array: `$return->stream->preview->small` will be that.